# Laravel Eloquent Relationship between users table and states table with states_id in users table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to figure out relationships in laravel and have come to the end of my rope so I thought I would post my very first question here in hopes of figuring it out. I can generally find the answer here but not this time.

I have the users table like so:

- id
- first_name
- last_name (etc.)
- address_1 (etc.)
- **state_id**
- city (etc.)

Then I have a states table

- id
- state_abrv
- state_name

Now from what I gather Eloquent wants the users_id stored in the states table instead of states_id stored in the users table but that does not make sense because you would have to repeat the states over and over.

On my User model I have tried

```
public function state()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
}
```

and

```
public function state()
{
    return $this->hasOne(State::class);
}
```

but I think it is looking for the foreign key on the states table and not the users table. What am I missing here?

I want to get a list of all users for example in the show user details view with their state without a second query to get all the states into an array and getting their state from that array.

Like

```
$users = User::with('state')->get();
```

Comment: Read the Eloquent relationships' docs more in depth. The approach would be your first attempt. If you follow Laravel's DB tables/columns naming conventions you shouldn't need to set the additional parameters for `belongsTo()` after the `State::class`. I think the error in this case might be the field `states_id` needing to be `state_id`

Comment: Laravel uses a library to do singular/plural transformations to manage this kind of things

Comment: I have read the Eloquent relationships docs several time and have been searching for an answer for days without any luck. One to One Eloquent will try to match the user_id from the Phone model to an id on the User model. I need the, in my case states_id on the users table not on the states table.

Comment: This has nothing to do with naming convention all that I have been using for a long time and totally understand. This only has to do with the relationship.

Comment: What about replacing `$this->belongsTo(State::class)` with `$this->belongsTo('App\State');` - Assuming your namespace is the default 'App'. I've never used the static class getter as you do on the relation. And also, have you defined the inverse of the relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I really understand what you want, you really will have to update the state method in your User Class by adding a second parameter.

```
public function state()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(State::class, 'states_id'); // if the column name in your users migration is state_id then you might not need the second param. 
}
```

Then you can get a user with the state relationship with

```
$users = User::with('state')->get();
```

I added `states_id`as a second param because that is the column name you have provided as in your migration

Comment: Okay I was not seeing it but now I do.